# Making test payments with Klarna on Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I've been attempting to make some test payments using Klarna on our Magento 2 site.

The customer address I'm using is a German address. When the Klarna modal pops up, it asks me for a phone number. I'm using +4901761428434 as advised by the Klarna docs.

https://docs.klarna.com/resources/test-environment/sample-customer-data/#germany

This appears to work and take me through to a verification code text box. Here I'm entering 123456 (have also tried other 6 digit codes) which displays an error saying "Whoops! That's the wrong code."

Would anyone be able to advise whether these are the correct credentials? Or could it be that my config settings in admin are incorrect?

Thank you in advance.